# The square of 44

Tags: riddle, movies

> I am made on a square of 44,
>
> preceded by purple, German and Germans
>
> then they sold meals for fifty pfennig

What am I?

---

Update: This one turns out to be hard. As the tag says, the answer is a movie. Also, do not hesitate to Google some of the terms or synonyms of them. I tried some terms that are not too hard to guess and then it will be in the first few hits.

Also, the title and the three lines contain a total of six hints.

Comment: is "movies" integral or incidental to the answer?

Comment: @question_asker What do you mean? The answer is a movie or something closely related to a movie.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question (I just wanted to know if it has something to do with a movie directly, or if it was just something that someone made a movie *about*)

Comment: First thing that came to my mind was [this movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/40_Quadratmeter_Deutschland)... but I don't think it's really related to the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess it's

> Das Veilchen vom Potsdamer Platz (The Violet of Potsdam Square)

Why?

> Admittedly this answer is the result of following your Google hint. However, there's merit to it:

made on a square of 44

> It was released in Germany in 1936

Preceded by purple

> The title begins with "The Violet" (aside: an interesting contradiction arises here -- it was released in English in 1939, but the German title uses "Veilchen" meaning the flower as opposed to "Violett" for the color)

then they sold meals for fifty pfennig

> The partial [answer by feelinferrety](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/27533) seems sufficient here

Comment: That was the intended answer.

Answer (score 6):

Well, since someone else went ahead and posted a partial answer, the fifty pfennig meals likely refer to

> Eintopfsonntag AKA Stew Sundays, a practice that was pushed as part of Winterhilfswerk (WHW), a drive to help support the Nationalsozialistische Volkswohlfahrt (National Socialist People’s Welfare Organization). Restaurants were required and families were encouraged to dull down their Sunday supper, donating the savings to WHW.  I found 50 pfennig referenced as the maximum amount to be spent on dinner.

Answer (score 5):

I am made on a square of 44

> I was made in the year 1936

Preceded by purple, German and Germans

> See the design and writing

Then they sold meals for fifty pfennig

> The value. I guess you could get a meal for a stamp, since they're of equal value?

What am I?

> A [stamp](http://ebid.s3.amazonaws.com/upload_medbig/9/9/4/1386443256-5789-47.jpg).

Comment: Where'd you get that date? As far as I can tell you're [15 years off](http://sorenm.com/content/23-1921-weimar-republic-stamp-catalog).

Comment: I also fail to understand what this has to do 'meals' and 'preceded'. Also, the tag explicitly says that the answer is something related to movies. (Otherwise it would be probably to hard to find). But I'm upvoting this just for the sake of the unexpected twist that fits reasonably.

Comment: @Will well, it's not really supposed to be the SAME stamp (I couldn't find one for that year, but who knows) but I was surprised about something like that explaining the "purple" and "german and germans" :)

Comment: @wythagoras Well I must admit I'm not a movie expert at all, but judging by the content it could be a some kind of historic war movie where something like this had relevance? The question asked "what am I?", not "what movie am I from?", so it's my best guess :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the movie

> Race

because

> Jesse Owens won four gold medals in the 1936 Olympics, which were held in Berlin that year.  I am still trying to tie in the meals and purple motif, but at least this may send someone down the right path.